# Why w3c created the property 'style' to determine all properties?

Tags: css, w3c

I would like to know why they created the property style for all properties instead of create a new property for each one?
Let me explain better, today we use this:

```
<p style="color:blue; background-color:red"></p>
```

I would like to know why they didn't do like that:

```
<p color="blue" background_color="red"></p>
```

Is there something in any w3c document telling it?

Comment: This sounds like a variant of [XHTML 3.0 Announced!](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/xhtml3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the `style` attribute, the development of new CSS properties doesn’t require an update to the HTML specifications.

If we’d have a separate HTML attribute for each CSS property, all these attributes would have to be defined in the HTML spec. So whenever a new CSS property is defined, all HTML specs would have to be updated. Otherwise this new CSS couldn’t be used in older HTML versions (validly).

In the same sense HTML doesn’t define graphic formats (like PNG) or codecs for audio/video, or the content of [`math`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mathml) or [`svg`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg).

So CSS and HTML developers can work separately from one another, as long as they respect the interface they agreed on: the [`style` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-style-attribute) (and the other ways to add CSS for HTML).

Another reason: It would be possible that other styling methods come up in the future, not compatible to CSS. Now when everyone would get their own attributes, that would become a total mess.

Answer (score 2):

My theory, based on logic...  Something like color="blue" is not CSS, it would inherently be part of the HTML language.

With CSS in the picture, there is no reason to expand on HTML to handle something that HTML was never designed to handle.  And so they made a way for HTML to read and understand CSS.  Hence the style="" property.

Why create something that is redundant when you can simply adapt to read what already exists?

That said, you used to be able to use things such as the `<font>` tag to recolor or resize text, such as `<font color="blue">`

As CSS becomes more and more powerful and expansive, there is no need to implement this type of styling, thus why the  tag is now deprecated in HTML5.

Beyond all reasoning there is a clear logical point, which is for each type of code to serve its particular purpose.  While they allow you to insert CSS into HTML inline by using the style="" property, it is not best practice and should be used in extreme and unique cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to point to where in the spec this is detailed, but I'll include my understanding.

I believe the intent was to promote separation of style from content.  The `style` attribute was introduce to allow for inline element styling, but the intended approach to styling was to do so using classes and external CSS.  This allows for reduced document size, as well as a generic content-only approach which allows for, among other things, a simple approach to theming.

`style` may also have been included to address situations where referencing an external stylesheet is either impractical or impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Because as much as possible, the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) is trying to abstract presentation (CSS) from structure (HTML) .. and if there are new properties created (attributes really) it would obscure the mark-up as well as making it more confusing (and harder to debug)

Its always best practice to use an external stylesheet whenever possible.